# Why is first call to Analysis Services slow

Tags: ssas

My application contains a pivot grid that is connected to several cubes in Analysis Services (SQL Server 2014).  When enough time has passed (maybe a couple of hours, I haven't timed it), the next time I use the pivot grid, I experience an increased lag time of 5 - 10 seconds compared to subsequent uses.  Basically, my first call to SSAS is always slow, all the next ones are fast.

I'm unable to find any documentation or article about why I'm experiencing a slow response time for my application's first call to Analysis Services.  Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

**Edit:**
I should mention that this is for a web application, so long load times are no good.  It seems like SSAS goes to sleep after awhile and I'd like to keep it "awake" if it's possible.

Comment: If you have a lot of databases, the first call to the server takes forever as it caches the information.  It's just the way it is...

Comment: @DanAndrews Is it possible to keep the server from going back into the state of needing to recache?  I get what you mean, but the server is not being reset from one day to the next, but each morning I get the lag time on the first call.  It seems like a service is being suspended after some period of inactivity, and I'd like to keep that from happening.

Comment: In the properties of the cube, what is the Proactive Caching set at?

Comment: @DanAndrews Standard setting, MOLAP

Comment: How often is it processed? Just at night or during the day? Are there lots of other SSAS or SQL databases on the SSAS server that might need that memory?

Answer (score 0):

At our shop, in the job that processes the SSAS database, we follow that step with some steps that run typical queries against SSAS to "warm the cache".

Seems to work for us.

Comment: Our's gets hammered so we don't have to worry about it except after a reboot or something.  Seem like there would be a better way to handle this.

Comment: If you think of one, let me know.   : )